# Passing defined function in np.where() for conditional output (Pandas, Python, Numpy)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I have the following sample DataFrame:

```
data = {'ID':            ['14','15','16','18','19','20','21'],
        'LOB':           ["BNK", "BNK", "BNK", "BNK", "XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ",],
        'US_ALL':        [False, False, True, True, True, False, True],
        'US_50_States':  [True, False, True, False, True, False, False],
        'Primary':       [False, True, True, False, True, False, True],
        'Secondary':     [True, False, True, False, False, True, True]}
```

I have the following defined function. My goal is to pass arguments based on the `LOB` column using conditional results.

```
def logic_for_bnk():
    # Country and State Flag Logic
    country_state_flag_conditions = [
        (df['US_ALL'] == True)  & (df['US_50_States'] == True),
        (df['US_ALL'] == False) & (df['US_50_States'] == False),
        (df['US_ALL'] == True)  & (df['US_50_States'] == False),
        (df['US_ALL'] == False) & (df['US_50_States'] == True),
    ]
    country_state_flag_values = [
        """%keep(criteria="country = 'US' and states_50 = 1", desc="Keep only US and in 50 states customers");""",
        "",
        """%keep(criteria="country = 'US'",desc="Keep customers in the US");""",
        """%keep(criteria="states_50 = 1", desc="Keep customers in 50 states");"""
    ]
    df['Country_State_Logic'] = np.select(country_state_flag_conditions, country_state_flag_values, None)
    # Primary and Secondary Logic
    primary_secondary_flag_conditions = [
        (df['Primary'] == True)  & (df['Secondary'] == True),
        (df['Primary'] == False) & (df['Secondary'] == False),
        (df['Primary'] == True)  & (df['Secondary'] == False),
        (df['Primary'] == False) & (df['Secondary'] == True)
    ]
    primary_secondary_flag_values = [
        """%keep(criteria="acct_ownership = '1' or acct_ownership = '2'",desc="Keep primary and secondary ownership");""",
        """%keep(criteria="acct_ownership = '1' or acct_ownership = '2'",desc="Keep primary and secondary ownership");""",
        """%keep(criteria="acct_ownership = '1'",desc="Keep primary ownership");""",
        """%keep(criteria="acct_ownership = '2'",desc="Keep secondary ownership");"""
    ]
    df['Primary_Secondary_Logic'] = np.select(primary_secondary_flag_conditions, primary_secondary_flag_values, None)
    # concatenating columns with SAS language output
    df['SAS'] = df['Country_State_Logic'].astype(str) + df['Primary_Secondary_Logic'].astype(str)
    # replacing all 'None' values with empty string ""
    df.fillna("",inplace=True)
```

Following the function, I have the following which is where I am having issues. I'm trying to pass the `logic_for_bnk()` function into the following new column using `np.where()`:

```
df['SAS Program Language'] = np.where((df['LOB'] == "BNK"), logic_for_bnk(),
                             np.where(df['LOB'] == "XYZ", "Pending XYZ Logic",
                             0))
```

I want my output to have 3 columns: `ID`, `LOB`, and `SAS Program Language` so I'm then adding the following `drop` argument to remove excess columns in the DataFrame:

```
df.drop(['US_ALL','US_50_States','Primary', 'Secondary','Country_State_Logic','Primary_Secondary_Logic'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

The issue here is that the resulting DataFrame contains 4 columns: `ID` `LOB` `SAS` `SAS Program Language`.

`SAS` is coming from the `def logic_for_bnk()` while `SAS Program Language` is coming from the new column I'm using along with `np.where()` arguments.
The `SAS Program Language` is passing `None` for `BNK=LOB` instead of the concatenated `df['SAS']` and looks like this:

```
   ID  LOB                                                SAS SAS Program Language
0  14  BNK  %keep(criteria="states_50 = 1", desc="Keep cus...                 None
1  15  BNK  %keep(criteria="acct_ownership = '1'",desc="Ke...                 None
2  16  BNK  %keep(criteria="country = 'US' and states_50 =...                 None
3  18  BNK  %keep(criteria="country = 'US'",desc="Keep cus...                 None
4  19  XYZ  %keep(criteria="country = 'US' and states_50 =...    Pending XYZ Logic
5  20  XYZ  %keep(criteria="acct_ownership = '2'",desc="Ke...    Pending XYZ Logic
6  21  XYZ  %keep(criteria="country = 'US'",desc="Keep cus...    Pending XYZ Logic
```

My goal is for the `SAS Program Language` column to have the concatenation defined in `def logic_for_bnk()` where `LOB=BNK` and have `Pending XYZ Logic` where `LOB=XYZ`.

Comment: The three arguments of each `where` are evaluated, and the results passed to the where.  That includes the `logic_for_bnk()`.  `where` is not an iterationor conditional evaluation tool. If that logic isn't clear, test some simpler cases.

Comment: I've tested with a simpler case and I can nest the where statements similar to an IF statement in Excel. The hiccup is calling the function into the where statement.

Comment: Try writing `temp=logic_for_bnk()` and `np.where( df['LOB'] == "BNK", temp, ...)`.

Comment: I am getting the following error:
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (7,9) (7,) `

Comment: So you have one condition per df row (the (7,)carray/series), but `temp` is a 9 column matrix or dataframe (7,9).

Comment: So making temp 7 columns should in theory fix the issue?

Comment: Changing to a (7,7) might get around the "broadcating" problem, but what you really want is for the other arrays to be (7,1).  But I haven't tried to understand your overall goal.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return anything! Add `return df` to the last line of your function. Other than that, it seems `pd.DataFrame.apply` is enough to create your desired output

```
sas_lang = df.LOB.apply(lambda x: logic_for_bnk() if x == 'BNK' else "Pending XYZ Logic") 
sas_lang.name = 'SAS Program Language' 

new_df = df.join(sas_lang)
```

Your desired output:

```
 new_df[['ID', 'LOB', 'SAS Program Language']]
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not my desired output. I see what you mean about the `logic_for_bnk()` not returning anything. However, my desired output is 3 columns, `ID` `LOB` and `SAS Program Language`. I tried the line you posted but it seems to be disregarding the `LOB` column completely.

Comment: I showed how to create a new series. You could add that to your dataframe, and return the specified columns easily afterward. I updated my solution nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded when I run ``df[['ID', 'LOB', 'SAS Program Language']]`` as the output.

Comment: Check the edit. It was becasue the function returns a dataframe so it was my bad to directly add that into a column

Comment: Thanks again! It's half working now. Now the issue is that for LOB=BNK, the result is concatenating the column headers instead of using the language in the function.